# Counter in a cronjob

Tags: shell, unix, cron

I am working on a cronjob script which works on a single if else condition. I need an echo in case the else part is executed 4 times. I cant use loop as i need to deploy the script in a cronjob. So please suggest.

Below is the sample script:

```
#!/bin/ksh
CheckFile=/home/tmp/check.txt

if [ -a $CheckFile]
then
 {
 print "date - @#@##@@#@#@#@#@#@##@#@#@#@#@#@@#@#@@#@#@#@ >> $LOG
 rm $CheckFile
}
 else
{
print "date - No checkfile present " >> $LOG echo
"###########################################break" >> $ERRORLOG
}
fi
```

Comment: you have a lot of errors here. Maybe better start pasting the code in http://www.shellcheck.net/ and seeing them. There is, in general, no use of `{` in shell scripts. Equality of integers is done with `-eq`, not `==`. `[]` expressions need spaces around, etc.

Comment: thanx fedorqui...for correcting me... could you please tell me if i can add a counter in a cron script.. as everytime it will execute.. it will set the counter to zero...is there any soulltuion to this type of scenerio

Comment: You probably have to keep a file with the counter, so that every time the cron starts it reads its value and then updates it upon end of running

Comment: fedorqui could you please share the flow of the script.. ,like where to declare the filename.. how to read it and where to compare

Comment: but your script has a `read` that does not make much sense for a cronjob: I assume you can say `echo "hello" | bash your_script.sh`, and then `$x` will contain `hello`, but it is unclear how you are going to work on this.

Comment: actually its a demo script which i was using for testing.. so i used a sample script... the main aim is i have to check the presence of a file  on my environment and if it is present its ok "if" part will be executed but in case it is not present for continuous 4 instances of the cron run then i need to execute few commands.

Comment: Better use the `edit` button to paste this code, together with a more general approach for the algorithm that you are mentioning.

Comment: fedorqui.. i have edited the sample script itself..

Comment: Voting to close as it is unclear what you are asking

Comment: Vorsrung....the question is simple..I have a logfile which is supposed to be present in a directory..i have put an if-else condition....i need to put this in a cronjob along with that i need to put a counter condition on the else part....that is ..if the "else" part is executed in the continuous 4 times execution of the cron,,, then i need ot fire a command in the lese part... but i ma not sure how i will set the counter because the cron will reset the values in every execution.